# Golang generics - simple use case

Tags: go

Say I have 3 structs:

```
type A struct{
   Foo map[string]string
}

type B struct{
   Foo map[string]string
}

type C struct{
   Foo map[string]string
}
```

and then I want to create a function that can accept any of those structs:

```
func handleFoo (){

}
```

Is there any way to do this with Golang? Something like:

```
type ABC = A | B | C

func handleFoo(v ABC){
   x: = v.Foo["barbie"] // this would be nice!
}
```

OK, so let's try an interface:

```
type FML interface {
  Bar() string
}

func handleFoo(v FML){
   z := v.Bar() // this will compile
   x: = v.Foo["barbie"] // this won't compile - can't access properties like Foo from v
}
```

In a language which encourages/forces composition, I cannot understand why you can't access properties like Foo.

Comment: Technically I don't think this is generics perse, it has to do with a type-hierarchy or interfaces

Comment: In every other case when you tell yourself "I need generics" be prepared to copy-paste like a maniac (or code-generate, which effectively is the same terrible solution)

Comment: For the types and `handleFoo` shown in the question, you can use  `func handleFoo(v struct{ Foo map[string]string })`  [See it in the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9CkeYIqkLiz).  This approach has limitations. For example, `handleFoo` does not have access to any methods in types A, B or C.

Comment: @ThunderCat thanks I updated the OP, let me know if it looks good

Comment: I am pretty certain I already tried that technique you just mentioned @ThunderCat, and it didn't compile, my guess was it had to be the same exact type by name/reference, not a different type with the same signature if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok @ThunderCat your solution works, can you please add that as answer? I am going to remove generics from the OP title b/c technically this is not generics tmk, but what would call this feature?

Comment: @ThunderCat thanks, this is what I observe so far: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/7bd67883a3e0ff4846c1ef5489ef8b43

Comment: Make Bar() return the map.

Comment: at(dustinevan) yup that's what @James Shi said

Comment: @AlexanderMills Unlike the question, the types in the gist do not share the same underlying type. If your intent is to use types that do not share the same underlying type, then update the question to show that.

Comment: @ThunderCat yeah for the OP it's too late to change that and would be unfair to the answers, but yeah I am curious how to do it when the structs are different, the only way I know how would be to program to `interface{}`

Comment: Go doesn't have generics. Trying to fake it is a silly idea. What is the goal of your code? Let's focus in your problem, rather than on your unsupported solution. As it is, this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Accepting different types is easy. That's what interfaces are for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the interface in this way, add a method `GetFoo` to get foo of each struct.

```
type A struct{
    Foo map[string]string
}

func(a *A) GetFoo() map[string]string {
    return a.Foo
}

type B struct{
    Foo map[string]string
}

func(b *B) GetFoo() map[string]string {
    return b.Foo
}

type C struct{
    Foo map[string]string
}

func(c *C) GetFoo() map[string]string {
    return c.Foo
}

type ABC interface {
    GetFoo() map[string][string]
}

func handleFoo (v ABC){
    foo := v.GetFoo()
    x:=foo["barbie"]
}
```

Comment: Yeah this works because all of them are basically the same. exact. type. lol..nice answer tho.

Comment: if one is `map[string]string` and another is `map[string]int` and another is `map[string]bool`, will it work? I don't think so

Comment: the value are different types. the interface should change to `GetFoo() map[string]interface`

Comment: @AlexanderMills they're all the exact same type in your own example code in the question. If you need something different, edit the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

Because A, B, and C are are all [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the same underlying type, you can use a function with an argument of that underlying type: `func handleFoo(v struct{ Foo map[string]string })`

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uggRvJ0kmxa).

A limitation of this approach is that methods on A, B and C (even with the same name and signature), are not available in `handleFoo`.

Comment: yeah this only works if all 3 structs have the exact same type, but unless something better comes along, will accept this answer soon

Comment: like I said, tecnically I don't think this is *generics* perse, but what language feature would you call this?

Comment: The types must be assignable to the same underlying type.  The types can be different as in the question and shown in the linked playground example.  The section of the spec on assignability is [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability).

Comment: I don't follow, the 3 structs in the OP are the exact same type?

Comment: A, B and C are different types, but they have the same underlying type.  Go does not allow assignment of an `A` to a `B`, but `A` and `B` can both be assigned to `struct{ Foo map[string]string }`

Comment: The language feature is assignability.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `reflect` and pass an `interface{}` to `handleFoo`

[https://play.golang.org/p/sLyjDvVrUjQ](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)

[https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/](https://play.golang.org/p/sLyjDvVrUjQ)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type A struct {
        Foo map[string]string
    }
    type B struct {
        Foo map[string]int
    }
    type C struct {
        Foo map[string]uint
    }
    a := A{
        Foo: map[string]string{"a":"1"},
    }

    b := B{
        Foo: map[string]int{"a":2},
    }

    c := C {
        Foo: map[string]uint{"a":3},
    }


    fmt.Println(a, b, c)

    handleFoo(a)
    handleFoo(b)
    handleFoo(c)

    fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}



func handleFoo(s interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    foo := v.FieldByName("Foo")
    if !foo.IsValid(){
        fmt.Println("not valid")
        return
    }

    switch foo.Type() {
    case reflect.TypeOf(map[string]string{}):
        fmt.Println("is a map[string]string")
        foo.Interface().(map[string]string)["a"] = "100"
    case reflect.TypeOf(map[string]int{}):
        fmt.Println("is a map[string]int")
        foo.Interface().(map[string]int)["a"] =  200
    case reflect.TypeOf(map[string]uint{}):
        fmt.Println("is a map[string]uint")
        foo.Interface().(map[string]uint)["a"] =  300
    }
}
```